# View based NSTableView, bind hidden property to shared user defaults

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

In my application I have a view-based NSTableView. One of the cells contains an image that I want to hide based on a user setting. So I bound the *Hidden* value in IB to *Shared User Defaults Controller* with *Controller Key* = **values** and *Model Key Path* to my setting. I use this setting in several other places in my code and am hence sure it exists. But to my surprise the image is always visible, as if I hadn't establish that binding at all. Also negating the value using `NSNegateBoolean` does not change the visibility.

In order to make sure it's not the actual user setting that produces the problem I tried another setting which I also have bound to a menu item (where it works). Still, same result. I can switch that setting with the proper result in the menu, but no effect on my image.

If I bind the hidden property to the **objectValue** of this cell it works as well. So to me it looks as if binding to the *Shared User Defaults Controller* is not supported.

Is this true and how can I implement it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings inside a view used in a view-based NSTableView only work to **objectValue** (and the application or application delegate object IIRC). Check the run log, it usually prints a warning that it'll drop this connection. I think it is odd that it doesn't allow bindings to app-wide shared objects, but it is what it is.

Only workaround I know is to implement support for the default in one of the valid objects.

Comment: There's no warning or anything like that. I can also bind to an array controller I have that won't have any effect either (since I feed the table view as a datasource delegate).